# convert decimal to hex missing padded 0

Tags: javascript

I have this function here:

```
function d2h(d) { return (+d).toString(16); }
```

So say I put `d2h(15);`.

This will return `f`. I need it to return `0f`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most obvious way would be to check if it's only one character, and if so, add a zero before it:

```
function d2h(d) {
    var s = (+d).toString(16);
    if(s.length < 2) {
        s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

A less obvious way would be this:

```
function d2h(d) {
    return (d / 256 + 1 / 512).toString(16).substring(2, 4);
}
```

But that's too tricky; I'd definitely stick with the first solution.

Comment: I forgot i had asked this question and basically implemented the same solution you had here. Thanks none the less

Answer (score 49):

Using `String.padStart`:

```
(d).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for large numbers as well.

```
function d2h(d) {
    var h = (d).toString(16);
    return h.length % 2 ? '0' + h : h;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function d2h(d) {
    var h = (+d).toString(16);
    return h.length === 1 ? '0' + h : h;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sdxZM/).

Comment: +1 as the middle ground between icktoofay's options, though I'd write `(h.length < 2? '0' : '') + h`. Personal preference.

Comment: Thanks see comment above on icktoofay